# How do I implement a CSP with jQuery without using unsafe-inline

Tags: jquery, wordpress, content-security-policy

I'm implementing a CSP in my company's Wordpress blog.  It's working everywhere except in jQuery.  I believe I have the script tag set up correctly:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://mywebsiteurl.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=3.5.1' id='jquery-core-js' nonce='96a155c5a23ce6c37c5c4c3677b8eee5b70f590145079ea9eb709a789369b53b'></script>
```

Then this is the important part of the CSP:

```
script-src 'self' 'nonce-96a155c5a23ce6c37c5c4c3677b8eee5b70f590145079ea9eb709a789369b53b' and so on...
```

This is the error I get:

```
"Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-96a155c5a23ce6c37c5c4c3677b8eee5b70f590145079ea9eb709a789369b53b'  etc etc. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-qqGbxWM7uia3gTh3zKaastub6jkpM0ypMYPp6TZvrLc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."
```

The error points to this line in jQuery:

```
doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score -2):

Your `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://mywebsiteurl.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=3.5.1'` loads **not** jQuery 3.5.1 because Google Chrome says:

`...Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-qqGbxWM7uia3gTh3zKaastub6jkpM0ypMYPp6TZvrLc='), ...'`

The `sha256-qqGbxWM7uia3gTh3zKaastub6jkpM0ypMYPp6TZvrLc=` is not a [hash of jQuery 3.5.1](https://csplite.com/ru/csp/sha/?pl=eJxLtDK0qi62MrZSKi3KUbIutjIzsFLKKCkpKLbS10%2FMSqzQS8%2FPT89JTSzILNZLzs8Fi%2BnnZCYV62cVlqYWVeob65nqGUI5elnFSta1AJj%2FHGQ%3D#result), whose real hash is `'sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc='`.

In case of `jquery.min.js` hash for v3.5.1 will be `sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=`.

Check what you load really, in case of jQuery forks their right work is not guaranteed.

Original jQuery 3.5.1 **supports** `nonce-value` ([proof](https://csplite.com/csp/test379/#test)).